# How can i receive Notifications while a modal dialog is open

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsnotifications

I need to send messages to the GUI thread which should be processed the next time the GUI thread is idle. This message can come from the GUI thread or background threads.

I tried a combination of a MachPort/Notification. But when i do a

```
[[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification: my_notify postingStyle: NSPostASAP];
```

This is not dispatched if there is a modal dialog, i have to close the dialog before it is processed so this is not useable for me.

It's okay to not handle messages during menu selection or live resize, but modal dialogs is a little bit too much delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  Don't use modal dialogs.

Long answer:  Modal dialogs are handled by a special run loop mode called `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode`, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html). 
To schedule a call, one way is to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:` explained in that document; don't forget to specify the modal mode and the default mode there.

You can also use `NSNotificationCenter` and specify the run loop modes, see [the discussion here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000217-CJBCECJC). But it's tricky to use `NSNotificationCenter` from the threaded environment to start with as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Threading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001289-CEGJFDFG), so I don't recommend it.

On 10.6, you can also use `dispatch_async`.

Comment: `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` seems to suffice to report to the main thread with a modal dialog, though the documentation does not make that clear.

Comment: Indeed. The documentation is not clear which mode it runs when `modes:` is not used.  Anyway I hate modal dialogs, so it doesn't matter for me:p

Comment: Thanks, yes i hate modal dialogs too and got rid of most of them (i'm porting a windows/linux app so there are many). But for example NSAlert does only work modal and i want to some data update work even if this poped up. But i will ask a new question about how to write a non modal NSAlert.